# Why does the same text look different in Word and PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

For no apparent reason, some of the diacritic signs are shifted during the transfer from Word to PowerPoint:

For example, this is how "ܩܛܲܠܬܘܿܢܵܝܗ̄ܝ" (Syriac word) it looks like in Word:
[image]

This is what it looks like in PowerPoint (after simple copy-paste):

[image]

You can see that the top line in the left part of the word - moved left. To get these results you need to define Syriac as a language and some fonts will install automatically. Specifically, this is Estrangelo Edessa.

Any ideas for that case? (Of course, any effort to return the vowels marks to their original place leads to further disruptions.)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the example text itself ([edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1612804/edit) the question)? I can't write it myself.

Comment: @harrymc - done, thx!

Comment: I remark that copy-pasting to Word results for me in the same text as in your second image (in PowerPoint). Which font are you using in Word (and where can I download it), and have you checked if PowerPoint uses the same font?

Comment: @harrymc  To get these results you need to define Syriac as a language and some fonts will install automatically. Specifically, this is Estrangelo Edessa. But any other default Syriac font causes this issue.

Comment: This manipulation is more than I would like to do. Does copy-paste of Word-to-Word work correctly?

Comment: @harrymc For me word-to-word works correctly but word-to-ppt failed...

Comment: It might be a matter of font, but I can't help more than that.

Comment: If it isn't what @harrymc is mentioning.. the font.. font or not, different programs *RENDER*  and scale fonts differently.  There is a built in win32 code to do this.. but these Microsoft programs are VERY advanced and do their own drawing because of things like support for scaling independent of the windows API.  Think about the fact that you can make it print sideways.. upside down, or even backwards.

Comment: Having worked at Microsoft, they do EXTENSIVE testing to make sure everything works within a particular program.. not so much on clipboard between the different programs.

Comment: Agreed : Seems like Word and PPT do not agree on the clipboard format. Which is why I asked if the font on PPT after paste comes out the same as the original Word font.

Comment: Does this only happen with copy-paste?  If you type into PowerPoint the same way you do in Word, does it look like it does in Word?  If so, does a copy-paste from PowerPoint into PowerPoint corrupt the text?

Comment: @TOOGAM this happens when typing too, not only in copy-paste.

Comment: I think it;s not an issue in the clipboard format. b\c I can type this string in the too apps and get different results. I mention the "copy-paste" b\c this string written in rare language so most of the users cannot restore that string in their word\ppt. @harrymc

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm not sure that is a clipboard issue, you can type it and see how this string gets wrong in ppt vs word. Maybe it's a rendering issue, how can I check it?

Comment: Do you mean that even when typing the text is wrong? This may mean that PPT doesn't use the font correctly.

Comment: @harrymc yeah, even when typing the text is wrong. What could I do if PPT doesn't use the font correctly?

Comment: As long as typing is not working, there is no point in trying copy-paste. You may signal the problem to Microsoft using menu *Help > Contact Support*, but this isn't an immediate solution. The only immediate solution I can think of is using in PowerPoint snippets of screenshots of the text in Word.

Comment: Yanirmr, I wasn't saying that it was a clipboard issue in any way.  I am not stupid and have been a win32 programmer for over 25 years.  The clipboard was merely the medium used to transfer the data between programs.  I was saying that Microsoft does not extensively test that data goes between programs and renders the same on each.  Internally, Microsoft uses a "special pretend font" to test text rendering.  They minimally test some of the more used fonts as do the translators that create the program text in a given language.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I am really sorry. I probably did not understand you correctly in the first post. This is my mistake. Thanks for the help and insights in trying to solve the problem. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problems sir.  I hope you are able to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As long as even typing the text is not working in PowerPoint,
although it is working in Word, there is no point in trying copy-paste.

You may signal the problem to Microsoft using menu *Help > Contact Support*,
but this isn't an immediate solution.

The only immediate solution I can think of is using in PowerPoint snippets of
screenshots of the text in Word.